# Refreshing the value of a python list tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask

I have the below flask code :

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

fruits = ["Apple","Mango","Peach","Pineapple","jackfruit","guava","banana","cucumber"]


@app.route('/index')
def index():
    response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_fruits/3')
    print (response)
    out = response.json()
    return render_template('index.html',fruits=out['fruits'])
    #return "Just checking"

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Home page"

@app.route('/get_fruits/<int:num>')
def get_fruits(num):
    global fruits
    sliced_fruits = fruits[:num]
    new_list = fruits[num:] + fruits[:num]
    fruits = new_list
    return jsonify({'fruits': sliced_fruits})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,threaded=True)
```

Now i have the below template file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test index page</title>
    </head>

   <body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function clickFunction(){
   var container = document.getElementById("fruits");
   var html_str = "";
   $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
              url: '/get_fruits/3',
              dataType: 'json',
              success : function(response){
              html_str = html_str + "{% for fruit in " + response['fruits'] + " %}" + "<li>{{ fruit}} </li>{% endfor %}";
              container.innerHTML = html_str;
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              console.log("There is an error thrown: "+textStatus);
              console.log(errorThrown);
              }
   });

   //console.log(html_str);
   }
   </script>
   <ul id="fruits">
    {% for fruit in fruits %}
        <li>{{ fruit}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul> 
   <button onclick="clickFunction()"> Check </button>

  </body>
```

Basically i want to refresh the value of the unordered list with a different set of fruits everytime i click the button.

The above code does not seem to work . So it all comes down to how can i refresh the value of the fruits variable in the for loop.How can i achieve the same.

Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template that you see with Flask is rendered server-side and isn't present in the resulting HTML. The web browser is literally sent:

```
<ul id="fruits">
    <li>Apple </li>
    <li>Mango </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

If you want JavaScript to be able to dynamically regenerate the HTML, you have three options:

1. Have Flask to generate the initial HTML and re-define your template structure in JavaScript.
2. Have Flask only define the initial data have JavaScript generate everything.
3. Have Flask generate the initial HTML and provide an API to allow JavaScript to have Flask render template fragments and send back the new HTML.

Since you're trying approach #1 already, you will need to redefine your template structure within JavaScript:

```
var new_html = '';

for (var fruit of response.fruits) {
    new_html += `<li>${fruit}</li>`;
}

container.innerHTML = new_html;
```

This approach has the downside of requiring you to implement HTML escaping and essentially duplicating your template logic.

Comment: This is basically a new scenario which i came up to solve the question that i posted on stack overflow earlier today : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021920/how-to-refresh-a-sqlalchemy-object-using-jquery-without-loading-the-web-page. Now from your answer it looks like an even more uphill task. Can you give me some hints regarding options #2 and #3 that you suggested.

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya: welcome to the central problem of full-stack web development. Look at technologies like react, angular, mithril, vue, backbone, etc. Their main purpose is to synchronize state like this.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the extent of the problem correctly, you can achieve this without having to require Jinja templating within your JavaScript. Consider the following:

```
function clickFunction() {
    var container = $("#fruits");
    var html_str = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get_fruits/3',
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function (response) {
        fruits = response['fruits'];
        container.html("");
        for (let f = 0; f < fruits.length; f++ ) {
            container.append(`<li>${fruits[f]}</li>`);
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("There was an error.");
    });
}
```

**Explanation**: You can use jQuery shortcuts to do the work for you. This finds the element with ID `fruits` and on `.done()` (or `success` callback) clears the list and iterates through the array inserting each list item after the other using jQuery `.append()` (also makes nice use of ES6 template strings!)

This, in my opinion, would work best since the AJAX call is still making request to the server and prevent Jinja templating in your JavaScript (which means you can place it in an external JS file).

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function clickFunction(){
   var html_str = "";
   $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
              url: '/get_fruits/3',
              dataType: 'json',
              success : function(response){
              for (var fruit of response.fruits){
              html_str = html_str + "<li>" + fruit + "</li>"
              }
              $("#fruits").html(html_str);
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              console.log("There is an error thrown: "+textStatus);
              console.log(errorThrown);
              }
   });

   //console.log(html_str);
   }
   </script>
   <ul id="fruits">
    {% for fruit in fruits %}
        <li>{{ fruit}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul> 
   <button onclick="clickFunction()"> Check </button>
```

My backend code :

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_fruits/3')
    print (response)
    out = response.json()
    return render_template('index.html',fruits=out['fruits'])
    #return "Just checking"

@app.route('/get_fruits/<int:num>')
def get_fruits(num):
    global fruits
    sliced_fruits = fruits[:num]
    new_list = fruits[num:] + fruits[:num]
    fruits = new_list
    return jsonify({'fruits': sliced_fruits})
```